# Create dynamic UILabel showing status downloaded file with NSURLConnection

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, download, nsurlconnection

I create one application that has one page.  In that page there is one button, label & a progressview.  What I want is starting a download when clicking on the button and show progress & label status download.

I can make progressview but I can not make a label that show download status.

For example, I want my label to show `"12 MB downloaded of 100 MB"`

This is my code:

**view controller.h**

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    float expectedBytes;
}
@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UIProgressView *progressView;
@property (strong,nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *download;
- (IBAction)download:(id)sender;

@end
```

**view controller.m**

```
@implementation ViewController
{
    NSMutableData *receivedData;
    NSString *currentURL;
    NSString *name;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    currentURL = @"http://192.168.1.100/mamal/Adele%20-%20Someone%20Like%20You%20(MTV%20Video%20Music%20Awards%202011)%20HD%20Live.mkv";
    name = [currentURL lastPathComponent];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
@synthesize progressView,download;
-(IBAction)download:(id)sender
{
    NSString* documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* foofile = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:name];
    BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:foofile];
    if (!fileExists)
    {
        [self downloadWithNsurlconnection];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"FILE EXIST");
    }
}
-(void)downloadWithNsurlconnection
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:currentURL];
    NSURLRequest *theRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url  cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:600];
    receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLength:0];
    NSURLConnection * connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
    [connection start];

}


- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
    progressView.hidden = NO;
    [receivedData setLength:0];
    expectedBytes = [response expectedContentLength];
}

- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [receivedData appendData:data];
    float progressive = (float)[receivedData length] / (float)expectedBytes;
    [progressView setProgress:progressive];
}

- (void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSLog(@"%@",paths);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *pdfPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:name];
    NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %d bytes of data",[receivedData length]);
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
    [receivedData writeToFile:pdfPath atomically:YES];
}
```

Please guide me how show status download in `UILabel` with `NSURLConnection`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put this syntax in .h file

```
@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;
```

then in .m file

```
- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [receivedData appendData:data];
    float progressive = (float)[receivedData length] / (float)expectedBytes;
    [progressView setProgress:progressive];
    [lable setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u MB of %f MB",[receivedData length],expectedBytes]];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an Outlet for the label

```
@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;
```

then in

```
- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [receivedData appendData:data];
    float progressive = (float)[receivedData length] / (float)expectedBytes;
    [progressView setProgress:progressive];
    [lable setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u MB of %f MB",[receivedData length],expectedBytes]];
}
```

you can change the bytes into MB

Comment: my friend I get one error in last line : "Too many arguments to method call"

Comment: actually was not on my Mac so couldn't test. Anyways looks like someone copy pasted my answer :p instead of editing it. still Edited ans now